# No Process Is on the Other End of the Pipe

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis

I receive this error when I try to connect to SQL Server 2005. I have enabled TCP/IP, Named Pipes, and restarted the server but that is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried the troubleshooting steps in both microsoft tech articles, and oddly no luck.

I managed to fix the solution by changing my authentication from SQL Server Auth to Windows Auth. Though I am not sure the technical reason why this works?

Comment: i had the same error since the user querying the db did not had permissions so i guess its a permissions issue

Answer (score 9):

For me the issue was that the SQL server was in Windows Authentication mode only, even though I set it to mixed during the install.

In the object explorer, right click on the server, properties and then the Security page and set Server authentication to SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode.

Answer (score 4):

FYI, I've just had the same error.

I switched to Windows authentication, disconnected, then tried to login again with SQL authentication.  This time I was told my password had expired.  I changed the password and it all worked again.

Answer (score 3):

It may help to make sure the database specified in the initial catalog exists.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when I (deliberately) reduced the configuration of maximum SQL Server memory to 16Mb and restarted.

So it might be a memory issue.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem when the password for the login that I was attempting to connect with had expired.

Answer (score 1):

One another reason for this error message could be the case when you've deleted the database your application uses, and you didn't run the following commands from your visual studio:

```
Add-Migration MigrationNameHere
Update-Database
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have seen this:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175496.aspx

how about this?
http://blogs.msdn.com/sql_protocols/archive/2006/07/26/678596.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1st check the Window's Event Log for the following error:

> Could not connect because the maximum number of ’1′ user connections
>   has already been reached. The system administrator can use
>   sp_configure to increase the maximum value. The connection has been
>   closed.

To solve the problem do the following:

- Open Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
- Open a new query
- Type the under given code and press the execute button

  ```
  sp_configure ‘show advanced options’, 1;
  GO
  reconfigure
  GO
  sp_configure ‘user connections’, 0;
  GO
  reconfigure
  GO
  ```

Source: http://www.windowstechupdates.com/microsoft-sql-server-error-233-no-process-is-on-the-other-end-of-the-pipe/

Answer (score 0):

In my case make sure that your connection string has ;password=

Answer (score 0):

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred
>   during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is
>   on the other end of the pipe.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 233)

This error will occur when the login does not have an active "Default Database" assigned.
In my case this occurred after taking a DB Offline. The previous DBA had assigned a non-system DB as the Default DB for a login. After that DB was taken offline, the login failed threw this error 233.

To Check & Fix this...
Login to the SQL Server Instance via SSMS using a different login.
Go to... >> Security >> Logins >> {Login Name} >> General

Check the "Default Database" is set to an active DB (I reverted back to 'master').

Logout & then try logging in again using the login that was just updated.

Answer (score 0):

in my case :

it was blocked by Symantec AV and firewall

just for trial I have to disable symantec n firewall

i think i'll have further checking

Answer (score 0):

If you have created the migrations, you could execute them in the Startup.cs as follows.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
 {
      using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
      {
            var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
            context.Database.Migrate();
      }
      
      ...
```

This will create the database and the tables using your added migrations.

If you're not using Entity Framework Migrations, and instead just need your DbContext model created exactly as it is in your context class at first run, then you can use:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
 {
      using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
      {
            var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();
      }
      
      ...
```