# SQL Server 2008 Connection Error "No process is on the other end of the pipe"

Tags: sql-server-2008

Let me begin by saying, I am aware of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451720/no-process-is-on-the-other-end-of-the-pipe) and others around the web that seek to trouble shoot this issue.

The solutions posted there do not apply to my issue.  I have spent 5 hours trying to resolve this before deciding to ask the question.

**The problem**:
When I attempt to log into SSMS (or connect from a java application) using SQL Authentication I get this error:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an
>   error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory
>   Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 233)

Although it does work, it is not an option for me to use integreated authentication.
The database I am attempting to connect to is on the same machine as my SSMS instance.  There is no network, this is a stand-alone system.

**NAMED PIPES is ENABLED** in my configuration, I HAVE rebooted since, TCP IP is a higher priority than named pipes in my configuration.

I have even gone as far as to uninstall SQL Server and reinstall it, to no avail.

The details of my SQL Server instance are as follows:

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - 10.0.2531.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools - 10.0.1600.22
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)  - 6.1.7601.17514
Microsoft MSXML - 3.0 5.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer - 9.0.8112.16421
Microsoft .NET Framework - 2.0.50727.5466
Operating System     - 6.1.7601
```

Configuration details are as follows:
http://i45.tinypic.com/vxdz7c.png
http://i45.tinypic.com/vxdz7c.jpg

I connect from java using this code.

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;database=AdventureWorks;integratedSecurity=false;User=JIMBO; Password=JIMBO;";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
```

But please remember, this error also occurs when I atttempt to log in to SSMS directly.
Thanks in advance.

-Jim

Comment: can you add your connectionstring? is sqlserver running on the same box?

Comment: Yes sql server is running on the same box.  This is purely prototype development.  I have added the code and connection string I use to log in from java, but the error also occurs when attempting to log in from SSMS.

Comment: Are you sure SQL authentication is enabled? By default only Windows integrated is enabled on sqlserver 2008.

Comment: It wasn't initially.  But I enabled it and rebooted.  I still get the same error.  http://i48.tinypic.com/v686rm.png

Comment: can you try with 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

Comment: Now I get a different error, which looks promising.  "SQLException:Login failed for user 'JIMBO'. Reason: The password of the account must be changed."  Just looking now for the config option to get rid of the password change requirement.  SSMS won't let me switch it off at the user account level.

Comment: Apparently that last issue is a known bug in SQL Server 2008.  I worked around it by changing the password manually: ALTER LOGIN JIMBO WITH PASSWORD='JIMBO1';  This is now working for me.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Presumably this has worked because it is using TCP IP rather than named pipes.  I still can't log in via SSMS, but this solution is absolutely fine for my purposes in this instance.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To force TCP/IP being used replace localhost with 127.0.0.1 in your connection string.

As you are using a username and password make sure SQL authentication is enabled. By default only Windows integrated is enabled on sqlserver 2008.

With SqlServer authentication keep in mind that a password policy is in place to enforce security.

Comment: Your answer fixed my problem; however, I would be interested to understand why. Another thing puzzled me: `(local)` wasn't working, but after one login using `127.0.0.1`, `(local)` is now successful.

Answer (score 4):

Forcing the TCP/IP connection (by providing `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` or `.`) can reveal the real reason for the error. In my case, the database name specified in connection string was incorrect.

So, here is the checklist so far:

- Make sure **Named Pipe** is enabled in configuration manager (don't forget to restart the server).
- Make sure **SQL Server Authentication** (or Mixed Mode) is enabled.
- Make sure your user name and password are correct.
- Make sure the database you are connecting to exists.

Comment: In my case all of those were checked and it still didn't work.  I never did get it working with the named instance, only with the IP address.

Answer (score 2):

My resolution was to login using the Windows Login then go to security>Logins locate the troubled ID And retype the used password. The restart the services...

Comment: Found a customer had a bad password and encountered this error. Strange that it did not throw a `login failed` error. SQL 2012 Web Edition, on 2012 Server.

Answer (score 2):

Adding "user instance=False" to connection string solved the problem for me.

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="NorthwindEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Northwind.csdl|res://*/Models.Northwind.ssdl|res://*/Models.Northwind.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS2008R2;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Northwind.mdf;integrated security=True;user instance=False;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem was caused for me by this error which appeared just prior in the application error log.

"A read operation on a large object failed while sending data to the client. A common cause for this is if the application is running in READ UNCOMMITTED isolation level. This connection will be terminated."

I was storing PDFs in a SQL table and when attempting to SELECT from that table it spit out that error, which resulted in the error mentioned in your question.

The solution was to delete the columns that had large amounts of text, in my case Base64 encoded files.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps this comes too late, but still it could be nice to "document it" for others out there.

I received the same error after experimenting and testing with Remote Desktop Services on a MS Server 2012 with MS SQL Server 2012.

During the Remote Desktop Services install one is asked to create a (local) certificate, and so I did. After finishing the test/experiments I removed the Remote Desktop Services. That's when this error appeared (I cannot say whether the error occured during the test with RDS, I don't remember if I used/tried the SQL Connection during the RDS test).

I am not sure how to solve this since the default certificate does not work for me, but the "RDS" certificate does.

BTW, the certificates are found in App: "SQL Server Configuration Manager" -> "SQL Server Network Configuration" -> Right click: "Protocols for " -> Select "Properties" -> Tab "Certificate"

My default SQL Certificate is named: ConfigMgr SQL Server Identification Certificate, has expiration date: 2114-06-09.

Hope this can give a hint to others.

/Kim

Answer (score 1):

For me it was because only Windows Authentication was enabled. To change security authentication mode. In SQL Server Management Studio Object Explorer, right-click the server, and then click Properties. On the Security page, under Server authentication, select the new server authentication mode, and then click OK.
Change Server Authentication Mode - MSDN - Microsoft
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms188670.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This Might help as reference

I had the same issue, after multiple trial of suggested solution on this site and others, I found a solution for my scenario. **The account was locked out**
How to Check if the account is Locked out... 
Login to the server using higher privileged account (like SA or admin rights)
Expand *security* ==> select the *login name* ==>open the *property* window of the login ==> select the *status* page on the property window

Make sure This **3** Things
1, permission to connect database is GRANTED
2, Login is ENABLED 
3, **Status** 
SQL server authentication 
Login is not locked out (**Uncheck the box**)

Thanks
Tsige

Answer (score 0):

I just executed connection.close() by adding it as first statement and it was solved. Then i removed the line.

Answer (score 0):

One follow up to this. I had installed SQL Server 2014 with only Windows Authentication. After enabling Mixed Mode, I couldn't log in with a SQL user and got the same error message as the original poster. I verified that named pipes were enabled but still couldn't log in after several restarts. Using 127.0.0.1 instead of the hostname allowed me to log in, but interestingly, required a password reset prompt on first login:

[image: SQL Server Password Reset Prompt]

Once I reset the password the account worked. What's odd, is I specifically disabled password policy and expiration.

Answer (score 0):

Another cause is if the user's default database is unavailable.

I had an account that was used for backing up two databases. When the backup user's default database was taken off-line, the "no process on the other end of the pipe" error started.

Answer (score 0):

Came here looking for a solution to a similar issue, which I just introduced by changing Schannel settings of our IIS server using "IIS Crypto" by Nartac... By disabling the SHA-1 hash, the local SQL Server was not able to be reached anymore, even though I didn't use an encrypted connection (not useful for an ASP.Net site accessing a local SQL Express instance using shared memory).

[image: The 'SHA' hash algorithm needs to be active for SQL Server to connect]

Thanks Count Zero for pointing me in the right direction :-)

So, lesson learned: do not disable SHA-1 on your IIS server if you have a local SQL Server instance.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue seems to have been caused by power failure. Restarting the server computer solved it.