# no process is on the other end of the pipe sql server 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis-7.5

I am developing a web application using VS2012 and SQL server 2008 using windows authentication. When I am executing my application from my local VM it;s connecting to the database and working properly. But when I published the applictaion in a server IIS it is giving this error."no process is on the other end of the pipe". Both are using d same database server. here is my connection string.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DbConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=XXXXXX200;Initial Catalog=XXXXX_XXXXX;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
       </connectionStrings>
```

Even tried with

```
Integrated Security=true; and Trusted_Connection=yes;
```

And also by removing

```
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient".
```

But still it's giving error. But the same thing is working fine from development environment. But note from hosted server.

Can you please help me where and what I am missing.

Comment: refer http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175496(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

refer this. this will give you instruction troubleshoot the issue
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175496%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: if you can't understand that. there is duplicate in stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585069/sql-server-2008-connection-error-no-process-is-on-the-other-end-of-the-pipe