# SQL Server 2008 Connection Error “No process is on the other end of the pipe”

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem where I cannot log into the database with SSMS.
I get an error of: A connection was succesfully established but an error occurred during the login process. Shared memory provider. No process is on the other end of the pipe.
I have enabled TCP/IP and Named pipes.
I tried to log in with Windows or Sql authentication but to no avial.
Please help as I have been struggling with this for a while now.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are already several questions on stackoverflow regarding this issue like...

[SQL Server 2008 Connection Error "No process is on the other end of the pipe"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585069/sql-server-2008-connection-error-no-process-is-on-the-other-end-of-the-pipe)

However, in my case it was a reason that was mentioned nowhere. I had played around with `SSLCert.exe` on a webservice in IIS last week. After i've restarted my server at weekend i could not login into my database anymore. After i've deleted the certificates and restarted the server again it worked without a problem.

So maybe this helps to solve your (or others) issue too.