# Connection String issue in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, connection-string

I am unable to connect to my database to insert data into it.

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection()) {
    sc.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DrugDB;Integrated Security=True";
    sc.Open();
    using (SqlCommand com = sc.CreateCommand()) {
        com.CommandText = "insert into Drug(DrugID,DrugName)values(@txtDrugID,@DrugName)";
       com.Parameters.Add("@DrugID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value=TBDrugId.Text;
       com.Parameters.Add("@DrugName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value=TBDrugName.Text;
}
    }
```

This is the error I get:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an
>   error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory
>   Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)

This in in my webconfig:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DrugDBConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=DrugDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=SOIS-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=testdatabase.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="ConStr" connectionString="Data Source=SOIS-PC\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=DrugDB.mdf; Integrated Security=True"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Plase help!!!

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/356619/A-connection-was-successfully-established-with-the

Comment: Are you sure the user is allowed to connect to the server ? Can you try connecting to the DB using SQL management studio ?

Comment: It is still erroring out!

    <add name="ConStr" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\SOIS\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\DummyPharmacy\App_Data\DrugDB.mdf"; Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>


It says missing required whitespace
Expecting end tag /add

Comment: I created the DB using Visual Studio. I cannot attach the DB through my SQL server. I do not know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be your SQL Server is configured to use NAMED PIPES instead of TCP/IP. Connect using TCP/IP, or use the **SQL Server Configuration Manager** to enable remote connections using named pipes. more info [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175496%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Also here is [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585069/sql-server-2008-connection-error-no-process-is-on-the-other-end-of-the-pipe)

Comment: Tried that. Restarting now.