# No process is on the other end of the pipe - solution?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012 and I have a database and have recently created a system admin account to log on using SQL authentication. When I restart the program after making the account, I open it to log on and it says :

> **Title: Connect to Server**
>   Cannot connect to .\SQLEXPRESS.

---

> **Additional Information :**
>
> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 233)
>
> For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=233&LinkId=20476
>
> No process is on the other end of the pipe

I have searched online for solutions and I have enabled TCP/IP, Name Pipes, and Shared Memory, yet no successful solution. Can anyone help and tell me how to solve this problem and actually successfully log on to my system admin account?

Comment: And in your online search you also found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585069/sql-server-2008-connection-error-no-process-is-on-the-other-end-of-the-pipe)?

Comment: Yup, but I don't understand the Java connection code and how to implement it my self.

Comment: Can you share your connectionstring?

Comment: I don't have a significantly made one. I just downloaded it and watched tutorials on the boot up, never mentioned anything about a connection string. So what do I do?

Comment: @rene I think OP doesn't use any connection string, Just wanted to log in to DB via SSMS ;).

Comment: I think this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/555332 can help you ;).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2008 Connection Error "No process is on the other end of the pipe"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585069/sql-server-2008-connection-error-no-process-is-on-the-other-end-of-the-pipe)