# What can be the cause of this SqlException?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

So there is C# written application (the data importer), that is being run on the different server than the SQLServer database. I connect to the database at 23:37 and then - at 00:16 - this problem appears:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server.  (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): No process is on the other end of the pipe.
>
> w System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>
>   w System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>   w System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>       w System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error)
>       w System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniSyncOverAsync()
>       w System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadNetworkPacket()
>       w System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryPrepareBuffer()
>       w System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadByteArray(Byte[] buff, Int32 offset, Int32 len, Int32& totalRead)
>       w System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryReadSqlValue(SqlBuffer value, SqlMetaDataPriv md, Int32 length, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
>       w System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadColumnInternal(Int32 i, Boolean readHeaderOnly)
>       w System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadColumnHeader(Int32 i)
>       w System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadColumnHeader(Int32 i)
>       w System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.IsDBNull(Int32 i)
>       w Company.Package.Importer.Database.TypeAwareDataReader.IsRemoved()

Do you know anything about issue? Should I recommend my user to check the SQL Server logs? Is there something that I can do on the application side? I do not have the direct access to the database (it's on my client machine).

**Edit after flagged as a duplicate**
I saw the [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585069/sql-server-2008-connection-error-no-process-is-on-the-other-end-of-the-pipe) but in my case I am able to connect to the database via SQL Server Authentication. I have even processed four tables before getting the exception. The fifth table is being processed for 27 minutes and them boom, the error appears.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585069/sql-server-2008-connection-error-no-process-is-on-the-other-end-of-the-pipe

Comment: I think I had that error message when the `SQL Server Agent` service hadn't started yet.

Comment: @Habib Thanks for advice. But it looks that the other guy could not connect at all using the SQL Server Authentication and in my case I am able to do that. I even processed four tables before that exception.

Comment: @y434y, yeah I wasn't use either if it is a duplicate or not, I haven't marked it, just commented. As far as your issue is concerned, Can you make sure that SQL Server "services" are running on the server machine ?

Comment: Check the logs, see if the sql service is restarting.

Comment: @dcreight You mean these logs? Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.n\MSSQL\LOG\ERRORLOG

Comment: @Habib I can check it but not right now - do you mean any specific service? I am not really into them at all.

Comment: Event Viewer on the SQL server, alternately in SSMS it would be under Management->SQL Server Logs.  There is a new log generated every time the service is restarted.

Comment: i also don't think it's a duplicate of that question, but being flagged as duplicate is no _accusation_, it's a hint and a way to keep the site usable. it is not saying that you're a bad user or something (maybe should research a little more - if it_was_ a dup). So no need to shout at the flagger.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this post: [provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075784/error-message-provider-shared-memory-provider-error-0-no-process-is-on-th)
and try to reboot your machine if everything was working!