# C# login failed when connecting to SQL Server database for unit testing

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-connection

I'm working on a project and when attempting to run a unit test to check progress, I get an error:

> Initialization method UnitTestProject.UnitTest1.Init threw exception. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "database" requested by the login. The login failed.
> Login failed for user 'User\User1'

I've checked that `User1` is owner in SQL Server and think I have the connection string right but I must be missing something obvious, please let me know :)

My repository class:

```
public class Repository
{
    private string _connectionString; 

    public Repository()
    {
        _connectionString = configurationManager.ConnectionStrings["database"].ConnectionString;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Person> GetPeople()
    {
        var people = new List<Person>();

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            string commandText = "SELECT dbo.People.Id"
                + ", dbo.People.FirstName"
                + ", dbo.People.LastName"
                + ", dbo.People.Height"
                + ", dbo.People.Weight"
                + "FROM dbo.People";

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);

            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    people.Add(new Person()
                    {
                        Id = reader.GetInt32(0),
                        FirstName = reader.GetString(1),
                        LastName = reader.GetString(2),
                        Height = reader.GetDouble(3),
                        Weight = reader.GetDouble(4)
                    });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);                
            }
        }
        return people; 
    }
}
```

My connection string in `App.config`:

```
add name="database" 
    connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=database;Integrated Security=true"
```

My unit test:

```
public class UnitTest1
{
    private Repository _repo; 

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Init()
    {
        _repo = new Repository();
        _repo.ResetDatabase();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GetPeople()
    {
        int count = _repo.GetPeople().Count();
        Assert.IsTrue(count > 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that creating a SQL server login with SQL authentication, i.e. user ID and password has allowed me to solve the login issue.

I then also had to update the connection string security from:

```
Integrated Security=true
```

to:

```
User id=admin;Password=password
```

Unfortunately I am now seeing this error when running the test:

> Initialization method UnitTestProject.UnitTest1.Init threw exception.
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A connection was successfully
> established with the server, but then an error occurred during the
> login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No
> process is on the other end of the pipe.) --->
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: No process is on the other end
> of the pipe.

However there are existing solutions I'll be trying from:

[No process is on the other end of the pipe (SQL Server 2012)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451720/no-process-is-on-the-other-end-of-the-pipe)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the  element to clear any connection strings that maybe previously defined:

```
<connectionStrings>
<clear />
<add name="DBConnection" connectionString="Data Source=xxxxxxxxxxx\xxxxxxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxxx"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />   
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Gave it a go but no luck. I just have the one database that I'm connecting to